# How to add GWT to a module in IntelliJ

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

How do I add the GWT facet to a module? When I google this, I get:

```
To configure default path to the GWT

Open the Project Structure dialog (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S).
Go to Facets, and select GWT.
In the Defaults tab, specify the path to the GWT installation folder. Click OK.
```

But there is no 'Facets' section anywhere. How do I get Intellij to pick up GWT? I have installed it already, but don't know where to go from there.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your IntelliJ edition.

The GWT facet is part of the Ultimate edition. There is no GWT Facet inside the community edition.

Comment: Ah, thanks for confirming that. I knew my old student email address would come in handy again one day ;)